# Implementation of own LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I am implementing my own `LinkedList`. I've a class which calls `MyLinkedLlist`, inside `MyLinkedList` only `size()` and `iterator()` have been implemented.  Besides I've one Abstract class where all my other necessary functions for `LinkedList` in. The abstract class prototype is:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractSequentialList implements List
```

I wonder if I need to implement `equals()` method inside my abstract class or it is already implemented for me because of I inherit `List`?

Comment: when i write "public abstract class MyAbstractSequentialList implements List" eclipse show me some methods but not equals().

Comment: actually how can compiler says if i need or not implement equals() method,because it is up to me?

Comment: there is no error when i didn't implement equals() method..when i call it for testing it works but returns false which shouldn't be the result

Comment: My bad, I expected a compile-time warning.  Noise deleted.  Hope you get a suitable answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List is an interface. So, there won't be any default implementation. You can choose to implement one if you need. Note that if you override equals, you must override hashcode as well.

Answer (score 1):

**List** is an interface and **equals()** is not implemented in **List** because all methods in any interface should be abstract.

So you have to implement **equals()** method in your abstract class. if not, you have to implement it in any subclass which extends your abstractclass.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an interface so if you want to implement in your own `LinkedList` so you have to override means implement `equals()` because there is contract with interface if you are implementing then you have to implements its methods as well.